# How to effectively grow user base of a discord server mutual aid group?

Tags: user-engagement, user-retention

I have some people who have joined to offer help, but no one yet asking for help. The group doesn’t have enough critical mass. Not enough people know about the group, that they could turn to it in times of need.

What is a most efficient way to do so? I mean that minimizing time and effort is a huge plus. Time and effort are finite, obviously. The less necessary, the better.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a community takes a lot of work and dedication, it's definitely not something that happens over night, might even take a year or two but that depends how dedicated you are. Posting on multiple platforms, hosting events, keeping the people engaged is what will build you up, meeting with other creators or admins, all these things will build you up.

If you have people willing to help then you as their leader should assign them each a job to do (ones that fit their role) don't make someone have a role of position just because they are your friend. You want people that are passionate about the same things you are.

Just advertise your server and constantly engage with the community even if you dont get a lot of feedback, everything will fall in line once you find a good base and team.